# resolvconf search no longer working in 17.04

Tags: 17.04, resolv.conf

I just upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 when I did I lost DNS access to my domains which I quickly realized in my resolv.conf file in a search line like:

```
search mydomain.com anotherdomain.com yetanother.com
```

Previously I would be able to `ssh myhost` and it would get me to `myhost.mydomain.com`.  This is no longer working.  With the `search` in my `resolv.conf` file, I get:

```
me@deepthought:~$ sudo systemd-resolve myhost.mydomain.com
myhost.mydomain.com: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

When I remove the `search` line I get a valid response:

```
me@deepthought:~$ sudo systemd-resolve myhost.mydomain.com
myhost.mydomain.com: 54.999.999.999
                    (ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com)

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 98.8ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

I looked at [the resolv.conf manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) and found nothing indicating this configuration is no longer valid.

Comment: I am seeing the same with 17.10.  Are you aware of a bug ticket for this?

Comment: Created one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1722722

Comment: There's some [details in this rant](https://osdocs.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/ubuntu-17-04-and-yet-another-round-of-i-fucked-up-your-resolv-conf-for-you-while-you-were-expecting-an-improved-distro/).
The actual bug is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320